# How to highlight only the actual differences in Vim diff?

Tags: vim, diff, vimdiff

When using *vimdiff*, it highlights the differing portion of the lines in a "greedy" fashion. That is, when comparing two lines:

Left window: **This one is his home**

Right window: **That one is her home**

then the whole line is colored pink, but on the left, `is one is his` and on the right `at one is her` parts are highlighted in red, as a mismatch:

> Th**is one is his** home
>   Th**at one is her** home

How can I make *vimdiff* only highlight the actual differences?

> Th**is** one is h**is** home
>   Th**at** one is h**er** home

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please visit https://github.com/rickhowe/diffchar.vim instead of https://github.com/vim-scripts/diffchar.vim. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, Rick - saw your answer after downloading and installing from @sudo's answer. I assume you are the author of the plugin? Is there a difference between the versions in the two repos (other than the much better Readme)?

Comment: Yes, diffchar.vim is my plugin. Please use https://github.com/rickhowe/diffchar.vim, which includes the latest version and is my own github repository.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built-in in vim to achieve this but you can use [`diffchar.vim`](https://github.com/vim-scripts/diffchar.vim) to achieve this.

After installing plugin, `vimdiff` will give you character wise diff.
You can toggle between this mode and normal diff using <kbd>F7</kbd> key

From plugin Readme:

> For example, in diff mode: ([DiffText], )
>
> ```
> (file A) The [quick brown fox jumps over the lazy] dog. 
> (file B) The [lazy fox jumps over the quick brown] dog.
> ```
>
> this plugin will exactly highlight the changed and added units:
>
> ```
> (file A) The [quick] <brown >fox jumps over the [lazy] dog. 
> (file B) The [lazy] fox jumps over the [quick] <brown >dog.
> ```

Comment: Thanks to @Rick Howe

Comment: Chose @Rick's answer over this, as he points to the more updated source.

Comment: vim F7, there are no default function mappings in vim.